# edit in ng-grid not working for numeric type

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have implemented a ng-grid..but edit functionality is not working properly...Its designed in  such a way that one column's inupt type is numeric i.e

```
 $scope.cellInputNumericTemplate = '<input type="number" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-
 model="COL_FIELD" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index">';

if(childtemp.fieldType=='Long' || childtemp.fieldType=='Double') {

  $scope.templateColumnDefs.push({field:childtemp.name, enableCellEdit:true, 
          editableCellTemplate:$scope.cellInputNumericTemplate});
 }


 $scope.gridOptions = {

       enableCellSelection: true,
   enableCellEdit: true,
       columnDefs: 'templateColumnDefs'
       //some other features as well included
 }
```

now i have other columns with type as string,date..etc and they are working perfectly fine but in case of this double and long i am able to enter the value the very first time but if i try to modify the value its not allowing me to do it..i.e edit is not working for that colum alone...

can someone plz help..

Comment: What browser are you using? input type "number" doesn't work in Firefox until version 28+ (if it shipped in that). If that's not the issue, can you create a Plunker? You could start with the ng-grid Plunker in the documentation.

Comment: You are absolutely correct..i was using firefox...now i checked in chrome and it works fine...i there any way i can make it work in firefox as well without verion update?? @lmyers

Comment: Added my thoughts as an answer. Would you kindly accept the answer since it solved your initial question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type "number" doesn't work in Firefox until version 28+ (if it shipped in that).

You can make the field a text field, and add a controller to it that watches the model. If the new value is not a number, don't allow it by setting the model value back to old value. Putting this in ng-grid adds a bit of complexity but it's probably do-able if you are persistent.

```
$scope.$watch('model', function(newValue,oldValue) {
  if (!newValue)
    return;
  var arr = String(newValue).split("");
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return;
  if (isNaN(newValue)){
      $scope.model = oldValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help...i included angular js file before jquery.js and that resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to say that the number cant be changed with up/down buttons.

In that case you also need to add step parameter to your input that changes with a lower rate than the default 1.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">...
```

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBQOCi?p=preview)

That what you wanted?

Another way to increment without using floating point steps would be:

```
step="any"
```

Just play around with the plunker.

Comment: Actually i can increment it the very first time but if i want to change the already entered value i am not able to do so...found out it was an browser issue..Thanks for ur help